# Play framework 2.0: Store values in Http.Context

Tags: scala, playframework, httpcontext

I'm trying to implement "request based" sessions in scalaquery in the play framework.  I create a session using scalaquery and attempt to store it in the current http context, as follows:

```
def withTransaction[A](bp: BodyParser[A])(f: Request[A] => Result): Action[A] = {
   Action(bp) {
     request =>
       val context = Http.Context.current()
       val session = createSession()
       session.conn.setAutoCommit(false)
       context.args.put("scalaquery.session", session)
       try {
         val result = f(request)
         session.conn.commit()
         result
       }
       catch {
         case t: Throwable =>
           session.conn.rollback()
           throw t
       }
       finally {
         session.close()
         context.args.remove("scalaquery.session")
       }
   }
}
```

then i wrap my actions in my controllers like:

```
withTransaction(parse.anyContent) {
    Action {
       //code that produces a result here
    }
}
```

However, it crashes in the following line saying:

```
val context = Http.Context.current() 
[RuntimeException: There is no HTTP Context available from here.]
```

So, why is the context not available?  This code is called directly by the framework, so shouldn't the context be set by the time this code executes? Or am i using the wrong way for accessing the context?

EDIT: The "session" is of type org.scalaquery.session.Session.  The reason why i want to set it in the HttpContext is so that the wrapped actions can access it in an "http scoped" fashion, i.e. That each request stores their session separately, yet all services that need a session can find it in a public scope that is separated per request.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is you're using the Java API with the Scala controller. `Http.Context` is only set if you're using the Java controller. Have you considered using the [Scala Session API](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.2/ScalaSessionFlash)?

Also, another question is, why do you need to store the session in the context? I see you just remove it at the end anyway. If what you need is for the sub-actions to be able to access the session, you could just pass it in the function.

I'm just going to assume `session` is of type `Session`

```
def withTransaction[A](bp: BodyParser[A])(f: Session => Request[A] => Result): Action[A] = {
   Action(bp) {
     request =>
       val session = createSession()
       session.conn.setAutoCommit(false)
       try {
         val result = f(session)(request)
         session.conn.commit()
         result
       }
       catch {
         case t: Throwable =>
           session.conn.rollback()
           throw t
       }
       finally {
         session.close()
       }
   }
}
```

and your sub-actions would be

```
withTransaction(parse.anyContent) { session => request =>
    //code that produces a result here
}
```

you don't need to wrap this in `Action` anymore since it's already wrapped by `withTransaction`

Comment: I can't store it in the session, since play sessions store information using cookies (max 4KB), thus, i could not store an object such as a database session there.  Also, i do not want to pass the db session as parameter to the action since the controller actions themselves do not directly rely on the session for anything.    I would have to pass the db session multiple layers down in order to take it to the services that need it, yet, i need to create it in the outermost scope since i need all low level services to use the same session, same transaction, and on a per-request basis.

Comment: By the way, you said that "Http.Context is only set if you're using the Java API", isn't there something similar to Http.Context.current() for scala then?  I mean, it must be a data structure that is stored on the server and that has a separate instance for each request. Http.Context is singleton, but when you call current, it gives a "Context" object that is different for each request.

Comment: I would have suggested using ThreadLocal, but apparently there are [problems](http://osdir.com/ml/play-framework/2012-03/msg02674.html) with that approach. Also, the author of play actually suggests [passing all parameters down](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/play-framework/LBUYHkp6dtU%5B1-25%5D) if you're using Scala, since it has implicits. So that would imply adding (implicit session: org.scalaquery.session.Session) to all methods involved in the chain of database calls.