# Http.Context with FakeApplication and illusive mock method

Tags: unit-testing, playframework, playframework-2.0, mocking

In my tests I create a fake application per test method:

```
@Before
public void startFakeApplication() {
    this.fakeApplication = fakeApplication();
    start(this.fakeApplication);
}

@After
public void killFakeApplication() {
    stop(this.fakeApplication);
    this.fakeApplication = null;
}
```

Some of the tests use functionality that checks if the request is secure or not:

```
public boolean isHttps() {
    Http.Request req = Controller.request();
    return req.getHeader("x-forwarded-proto") != null
            && req.getHeader("x-forwarded-proto").contains("https");
}
```

That fails saying:

> There is no HTTP Context available from here

Which is pretty strange, since it's running on a fake app, why can't it know that and create a fake request?
Oh well, I found this: [Play framework 2.2.1: Create Http.Context for tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20206270/play-framework-2-2-1-create-http-context-for-tests) which introduced me to the mocking approach, so I was eager to give it a go and try to mock the `Http.Context` in the same way, the problem is that I can't seem to find the `mock` method...

In that thread he's using `import static org.mockito.Mockito.*` (which is where I assume the `mock` method is located) but I don't have that package, `org.mockito` only has one sub package named `internal` and I can't find any `mock` method there.

In the official documentation of Play! the only place talking about it is the [Scala Test](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ScalaTest) section and they use: `import org.specs2.mock._` but there too I wasn't able to locate this `mock` method.

I'm using Play 2.2.2 (java).
Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the same problem adding to my `build.sbt` the library dependency of Mockito:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.mockito" % "mockito-core" % "1.10.19"
```

Then I run `play compile` and `play eclipse` and magically the mockito library became available after refreshing the whole project in Eclipse.

And yes, `mock()` is a method of `org.mockito.Mockito`.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem of Play not locating the mock function, and eventually realised that I hadn't extended my test class with Mockito;

```
import org.specs2.mock._

class TestClass extends Specification with Mockito
```

Just thought I'd add this as it has taken me ages to resolve and the above solution didn't work for me ......may save someone some time :)